# Error when attempting to disable account - BOX Api v2

Tags: box-api

I am attempting to disable a user account using the BOX 2.0 API. However, I am receiving a 400 status code error. In an effort to troubleshoot, I attempted to update a user attribute but once again received the 400 status code error. I even received the error when using the example in the documentation for updating user information (with my own parameters of course).

I am utilizing Powershell 3.0. I thought maybe I had something wrong in the syntax but received the exact same error using Postman in Chrome. Any guidance would be appreciated!

**My Code:**

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://api.box.com/2.0/users/USER_ID \
    -method PUT \
    -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"} \
    -Body @{"status"="inactive"}
```

**Error:**

> {"type":"error","status":400,"code":"bad_request","help_url":"http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors","message":"Bad
>   Request","request_id":"1028858396513419e934e95"}

Answer (score 1):

are you an administrator in this account? If you are an administrator, are you attempting to set another admin user to inactive? You will need to not only be an admin, but have privileges above the user that you're attempting to set to inactive.

Comment: Yes, the account used to generate the access token is an admin in our Enterprise BOX account. I am using the same authentication to export a list of all enterprise user accounts which I believe also requires admin access. The user account I am attempting to disable is a standard user account (not an admin).

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this on a both a main and co-admin account and I'm unable to reproduce. I wonder if you're making a syntax error somehow. Have you tried in command line with cURL?